# Ggplot2 adding simple customizable minor tick marks revisited

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm aware that this is a long-standing problem: setting unlabelled, customizable minor tick marks in ggplot2. I find this post containing a work-around to offer 2 solutions that are somewhat customizable the best, but won't work for me personally: [Quick, sleek and simple way of adding minor ticks in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64174750/quick-sleek-and-simple-way-of-adding-minor-ticks-in-ggplot2).

To my understanding you just plot all major tick marks and set the labelling of some of these, the ones that are supposed to be minor tickmarks, to NULL or "". Thus, the minor tickmarks won't have a label, but the major tickmarks will. This works, but I would like my minor tickmarks to be smaller than major tickmarks and since you cant distinguish between the two here, it doesn't work.

I don't necessarily mind typing out where the minor ticks should be placed each time, as long as this is easy to do consistently.

Given the following fictional dataset and code, is it possible to make **minor** y-axis ticks here **inbetween** the major ticks at intervals to lets say every 0.25 that are **smaller** than the major ticks?

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create some sample data
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 50),
                   value = c(rnorm(50, mean = 10), rnorm(50, mean = 20)))

# Create the plot using ggplot2
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = group, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot()

# Duplicate the y-axis
p + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis()) + theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The {ggh4x} package has a guide function for adding minor tick marks.

For basic usage, you can add it by using the `y = "axis_minor"` in the `guides()` function.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

# Create some sample data
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 50),
                   value = c(rnorm(50, mean = 10), rnorm(50, mean = 20)))

# Create the plot using ggplot2
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = group, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot()

p + guides(y = "axis_minor")
```

[image]

If you need more control over *where* they are placed, use the `minor_breaks` argument of the scale. If you want to control the length of the minor breaks, you can use the `ggh4x.axis.ticks.length.minor` theme setting. Note that it specifies the minor ticks length relative to the major tick length.

```r
p + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    minor_breaks = scales::breaks_width(1),
    guide = guide_axis_minor()
  ) +
  theme(ggh4x.axis.ticks.length.minor = rel(2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x. Also, the guide function might become deprecated in 2 cycles of ggplot2 development.

Comment: that's interesting inside information. I've closed this question as the same solution was already suggested in the far more "famous" thread. Thanks as usual for your fantastic work

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to smuggle minor axis ticks into vanilla ggplot2, so no need for me to maintain ggh4x's then ;D

Comment: If I can't smuggle it into ggplot2, I'll just go maintain a separate package for all the axis functions

Comment: May I suggest "ggh4xis".

Comment: hahaha, nah it'll include other guides as well legends/colourbar variations and such

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `ggh4x` package with `ggh4x.axis.ticks.length.minor` with `rel` of for example 0.5 to make smaller ticks at certain `minor_breaks` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)
# Create some sample data
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 50),
                   value = c(rnorm(50, mean = 10), rnorm(50, mean = 20)))

# Create the plot using ggplot2
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = group, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot()

# Duplicate the y-axis
p + scale_y_continuous(
  minor_breaks = seq(8, 22, by = 0.25),
  breaks = seq(8, 22, by = 4), limits = c(8, 22),
  guide = "axis_minor"
) +
theme(ggh4x.axis.ticks.length.minor = rel(0.5)) + 
theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi Quinten, I get the following error when adding the piece of code you suggested within the "scale_y_continous" call in my own code: **Error in ticks$.label[is_major] <- scale$get_labels(breaks[is_major]) : 
  replacement has length zero**

Comment: Hi @pleasehelp, This error means that you are assigning a value of length zero to the function. Are you sure you copied the code right?

Comment: Hi Quinten, apologies, I copied parts of your code into the code I'm using to make a plot. Using your exact code on the example dataset works! Perhaps you take a quick glance at this piece of code and see where the problem is (I'm going for a boxplot, with axis surrounding the plot and ticks pointing inwards, hence the duplicated axes and negative values for ticklength) which has y-axis minor tick marks:

Comment: `data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Line_num,y=log_FC, group=interaction(Line_num, Treatment))) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar', width=0.15, position = position_dodge(width=0.6)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA, width=0.4, position = position_dodge(width=0.6)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-3, 2), breaks = seq(-3, 2, by=1), minor_breaks = seq(-3, 2, by=0.25), sec.axis = dup_axis(name=NULL, labels=NULL)) + theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.1, "cm")) + scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name = NULL, labels = NULL)) + theme(axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'black', size = 1)) `

Comment: @pleasehelp, why do you use `NULL` in your `dup_axis` arguments?

Comment: Because, if I understand my own code correctly, it removes the second y-axis label and major tick labels. I typically dont use those, I just like to have axis around the plot if you have many groups (and thus boxes) so that the boxes fartest away from the primary y-axis are still close to another axis for checking values. I add the major tick values separately in annotation programs like Adobe Illustrator later, since these values often will either be plotted inside or outside the plot margins. Something that I'm too lazy to fix in the code.

Comment: @pleasehelp, Could you please try with NA instead of NULL?

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work. I get the following error: `Error in `get_labels()`:
! Invalid `labels` specification. Use "NULL", not "NA"`